# css skew transformation in IE 7 & 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have rhombus styled menu which uses the following code. It works fine in Chrome, firefox, ie9 etc but i now need to get this working in IE 7 & 8! :( Is there a way to do this on these legacy browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/C7e7U/

Many Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id = "menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="rhombusStart">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Market <br> Update</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>Membership</span></a></li>
            <li class="rhombus"><a class="rhlink" href="#"><span>FISC Info</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="rhombusEnd">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*******************************************
 Menu Styling
*******************************************/
#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 2%;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 2.9em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    border: 1px solid rgb(140,51,61);
}
#nav {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
     height:2.9em;
     background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
}

#nav > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#nav > li.rhombus {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:skew(35deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(35deg);
    transform:skew(35deg);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(239,89,24);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(255,244,80);
    background-color: rgb(255,194,14);
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: rgb(131,0,26);
    width: 8em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 2.9em;
}

li.rhombus > a span {
    -webkit-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -ms-transform:skew(-35deg);
    -o-transform:skew(-35deg);
    transform:skew(-35deg);
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;     
 }
```

Comment: css transform does not works with IE6, IE7 or IE8. You can use transparent png's as a background image for menus but that will work for IE8. You will have to use pngfix (google it) or something for IE7.

Comment: You could attack this problem from another direction: you could use the slanted border trick on both side + some negative margins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242262/how-to-create-diagonal-heading-line-with-pure-css/

Comment: ... or using css3 gradients + css3pie for IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient http://css3pie.com/

Comment: The slanted border trick looks interesting but how would I have a border around that?

Comment: That's all I could do: http://jsfiddle.net/C7e7U/2/

Comment: Great effort!, but needs some work, not sure how easy it would be getting dropdowns on that and changing backgrounds on hover though

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/visionmedia/move.js just downlaod this and read its documentation to work your CSS3 in old browser