# How to Create Diagonal Heading Line with Pure CSS

Tags: css

how we can create a diagonal heading line with **pure CSS** like mentioned below image :-

[image]

Comment: why did you updated the image?

Comment: why i can't update the question F.calderan.

Comment: I didn't say that "you cannot": I just asked why you did it :). My question is due to the fact that I was preparing a demo with the previous style

Comment: :-) hehehee you can share your answer now as well as........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the most appropriate example (the image you provided *before you updated your question* is the same):
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Rohit AZAD</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {

  padding:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  height:0;
  line-height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-right:30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:30px solid blue;

}
```

demo :- http://jsbin.com/uhibub/edit#html,live

Comment: yup its same like that i am looking the various solutions for that if you have u can share your knowledge with us

Comment: that link offers a complete explanation to accomplish the wanted result (demo included...)

Comment: i know but looking some solutions to that so wht a big deal in that if we are sharing a information on this platform F.Calderan and we should share if we know some thing better....am i right i think...

Answer (score 3):

By using the `:after` pseudoelement and transparent borders, it's easy. If you add the `:before` part, you even get anti-aliasing (of course it is your task to calculate the 50% color):

http://jsbin.com/ejomav/3/edit#javascript,html,live

```
​<div>New Music</div>
<div>Old Music</div>

div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.5em;
    line-height: 2em;
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
div:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right:        -2em;
    border:        1em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1em solid black;
    border-left:   1em solid black;
}

div:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:  0px;
    height: 0px;
    top:    0px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    right:        -2em;
    border:        1em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1em solid #8080FF;
    border-left:   1em solid #8080FF;
}
```

Comment: Actually the version linked by F.Calderan is better in my opinion :)